# Exception when running QUnit test script in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing, qunit, chutzpah

I'm encountering an issue when I try to run a QUnit test script for a JavaScript file in Visual Studio 2022. The error message thrown reads:

System.ArgumentException: The specified argument cannot be empty. Parameter name: filters

I've included the full stack trace of the exception in the code block below. Can someone provide assistance on how to resolve this issue?

````
Executing all tests in file: Main.testfile-test.js
System.ArgumentException: The specified argument cannot be empty.
Parameter name: filters
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ValidateArg.NotNullOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 arg, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQueryBySolutionContext.<GetTestContainerConfigurationsInternalAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQuery.<GetTestContainerConfigurationsAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestRunConfiguration.<UpdateAfterTestDiscoveryAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RunOperation.<RunTestsAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RunOperation.<RunTestsAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RunOperation.<RunTestsAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RunOperation.<ExecuteInternalAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<<ExecuteAsync>b__43_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Logging.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__11`1.MoveNext()```
````